# Is there a way, in VSCode, to preserve all user input linebreaks, and format all other linebreaks

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to add multiple empty lines to separate code visually. But I'd like to be able to format all other empty lines out.

example: If I delete 3 lines of code, on save, I want the formatter to scoot the code up 3 lines. But if I add 3 empty lines to separate my code, on save, I dont want these lines to be formatted out.

Comment: so if you **delete** a line you leave the line feed and let the formatter delete the line feed for you, why add 3 lines empty space, 1 line is enough, limits the amount you have to scroll, maybe you do it to get a higher line count in the blame statistics, that type of code would never pass my review

Comment: is this an answer to the question? if so please clarify